# Trying to create a map of string -> functions, a sort of request handler. Issue with return types of the function map

Tags: go

So I've currently got the following code:

```golang
type handlerFunc func(*nats.Conn, *zerolog.Logger, item) interface{}  // This is the issue
type handlerFuncID func(*nats.Conn, *zerolog.Logger, item, string) interface{}  // This is the issue

func (app *App) Run() {
    mapHandlers := map[string]handlerFunc{
        "RETRIEVE": handlers.RetrieveItems,
        "CREATE":   handlers.CreateItem,    
}

    mapIDHandlers := map[string]handlerFuncID{
        "RETRIEVE": handlers.RetrieveItemById,
        "UPDATE":   handlers.UpdateItemById,
        "DELETE":   handlers.DeleteItemById,
    }
```

The point of this is to have a sort of map which should work like this:

```golang
if _, v := params["item_id"]; v {
    // A call with ID in params
    itemID := params["item_id"].(string)
    resp = mapIDHandlers[method](app.nc, app.logger, item, itemID)
} else {
    // A call without ID in params
    resp = mapHandlers[method](app.nc, app.logger, item)
}
```

It works perfectly fine if I replace the interface{} return type (in the first two lines of the first code block) with the return type of one RetrieveAll, but that doesn't work for CreateItem, because it only returns one item.

Is there a way to make the return type of the handlerFunc of type ANY?
As I'm converting it to JSON right after, it makes no difference anyway.

Comment: What are the signatures of RetrieveAll and CreateItem?

Comment: in the case of the `handlerFunc` type, methods `handlers.RetrieveItems` and `handlers.CreateItem` must have the same function signature, which is `func(*nats.Conn, *zerolog.Logger, item) interface{}`. They cannot be `func(*nats.Conn, *zerolog.Logger, item) int` or `func(*nats.Conn, *zerolog.Logger, item) []int`.

Comment: @BurakSerdar as specified by the comment before, they are []item and item which now makes me rethink the whole design.

Comment: @eminlala thank you for the answer, I'll be looking for a different solution for my design.

Comment: You can still have handlers with different signatures, but construct your handler map using an adapter: `"RETRIEVE": func(someargs) interface{} {return handlers.RetrieveItems(someargs);}`

Comment: Looks promising! Will check it out, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I've found an answer to what I was looking for, thanks to @Burak Serdar and more searching around.

```golang
mapHandlers := map[string]interface{}{
        "RETRIEVE": func(nats *nats.Conn, logger *zerolog.Logger) model.ItemsListResponse {
            return handlers.GetItems(nats, logger)
        },
        "CREATE": func(nats *nats.Conn, logger *zerolog.Logger, item model.Item) model.ItemResponse {
            return handlers.CreateItem(nats, logger, item)
        },
    }
```

Essentially this is about how my handlers look like. In my code, I had to check for the corresponding args and call the right function, which looks like this:

```golang
fn := mapHandlers[method]

switch m := fn.(type) {
case func(*nats.Conn, *zerolog.Logger) model.ItemsListResponse:
    responseJsonrpcmsg.Result = m(app.nc, app.logger)
case func(nats *nats.Conn, logger *zerolog.Logger, item model.Item) model.ItemResponse:
    item := model.Item(...args)
    responseJsonrpcmsg.Result = m(app.nc, app.logger, item)
default:
    app.logger.Error().Msg("Something went wrong in the request handler")
}
```